# How to create an automatic task in php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, cron

On my page :

- **Users create tournament interface** using `fopen()` and `fwrite()`.
- The tournaments created **must start after a certain time**, say 1 hour.
  This I do to give time to the other users to enter by means of a button.
- When the time ends **the users that entered are organized**.

At the moment of creating the tournament, how can I program a timer so that when I finish executing the code to organize.

Of course I researched ​​but on the internet I only found things like the 
`timer` event with `Javascript`:

```
<body onload="setTimeout(myFunction, 3000)">Try it</body>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
        //code
    }
</script>`
```

or using `sleep()` of `PHP`

But all these options will depend on the user, ie **if you close the browser** the script to organize will not run.

Then I need to create a task that at the end of time **runs the organization script even though the user has not interacted**.

I do not know if I explained well but any answer is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to store the time in Cookies, then you can access it if browser closed,
Apartform that, If you want more actual performance
- Implement user logins
- Store the time with login details inand your DB
- Check the login and time for next time

Answer (score 1):

You can send a AJAX Request to your PHP Script, which returns a number, how long the Javascript should wait until the Tournament begins.